# Proof of this inequality

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, inequality

I have a finite sequence of positive numbers $(a_i)_1^n$ for which:

1. $a_1>a_n$,
2. $a_j\geq a_{j+1}\geq\cdots\geq a_n$ for some $j\in\{2,\ldots,n-1\}$,
3. $a_1>a_2>\cdots>a_{j-1}$,
4. $a_j\geq a_i$ for all $1\leq i\leq n$.

I conjecture that:

$$(a_n+a_2+\cdots+a_j)\left(\sum_{i=j+1}^{n-1}{\frac{a_i^2}{(a_1+\cdots+a_i)(a_n+a_2+\cdots + a_i)}}+\frac{a_1+a_n}{a_1+\cdots+a_n}\right) \geq  (a_n+a_1+\cdots+a_j)\left(\sum_{i=j+1}^{n-1}{\frac{a_i^2}{(a_1+\cdots+a_i)(a_n+a_1+\cdots + a_i)}}+\frac{a_n}{a_1+\cdots+a_n}\right).$$

I have an unappealing brute-force proof when $n\in\{3,4,5\}$  but I can't prove it in general. I have tried calculus to no avail, and it doesn't seem like a good fit for any of the standard inequalities.Does this look even remotely similar to anything already done? I appreciate that it's a rather ugly inequality but some suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

The proof when $n=3$ is outlined below. By condition 2. we know that $j=2$ so that

\begin{align*}
(a_3+a_2)\left(\frac{a_1+a_3}{a_1+a_2+a_3}\right)-(a_3+a_1+a_2)\left(\frac{a_3}{a_1+a_2+a_3}\right)=\frac{a_2(a_1-a_3)}{a_1+a_2+a_3}>0
\end{align*}
where we have used condition 1, which states that $a_1>a_3$.The proofs when $n=4$ and $n=5$ are likewise, only uglier. When $n=5$ the trick is to find common denominators then simply pair each negative term with some larger positive term. It's horrible, but it works. Perhaps a general proof would involve a similar argument but more formalised?

If a full proof can't be found then I'd be happy for a proof in the special case where $j=2$ and $j=3$.

Comment: Hint: Compare $a_1$ times smaller sum against the terms in the larger sum that come from having $a_1$ in the numerator of the rightmost fraction inside the sum (it's a bit messy to write down, but you should be able to get the desired inequality from those pieces, as the rest is shared by both sums).

Comment: Condition (2) says "where $2\leq j\leq n-1$" -- is that supposed to mean "for all $j$" in that range? Or is there supposed to be some particular $j$ in that range for which the statement holds?  Is Condition (3) then supposed to be stating that this particular $a_j$ is at least as large as any other $a_i$? (Otherwise, for which $j$ is Condition (3) supposed to hold?)

Comment: I will clarify. Thanks for pointing out the ambiguity.

Comment: So the inequality is only required to hold for *some* $j$ satisfying Conditions (2) and (3)?

Comment: Yes, that is right. The $j$ is determined by the sequence itself. Suppose we have the sequence $\{4,2,1,6,4,5,3\}$. Then $j$ could be $4$ or $5$. But in both instances, the left hand side is greater than the right hand side.

Comment: Assuming it's true, it should hold for any $ j$ such that $ 2<j<n$ under the weaker conditions $0<a_1$ and  $1\leq i<n\implies$ $a_i\geq a_{i+1}\geq 0.$

Comment: You've revised to four conditions, and you comment that for "$\{4,2,1,6,4,5,3\}$. Then $j$ could be $4$ or $5$". How can that be? Conditions (3) and (4) imply $j=4$ (because $a_4$ is greater than any other element, and its predecessors are strictly decreasing), but Condition (2) implies $j=6$ (because the "tail" has to be nonincreasing) -- a contradiction; so there is no valid $j$ for that sequence.

Comment: Sorry about that. I realised that there is a reason why I can assume that the terms prior to the largest are decreasing. So for the sequence quoted we must have $j=4$.

Comment: No, this sequence cannot have $j=4$, for the reason I stated: Condition (2) would then  require $a_5 \ge a_6\ge a_7$, which is not the case for the quoted sequence. (For this sequence, there *is* no $j$ that satisfies all the conditions you've given.)

Comment: Ahh....sorry, yes, there is a typo in the sequence that I gave. I meant to say: $\{4,2,1,6,5,3\}$. In this case, $j=4$.

Comment: I'm curious about the context here. What is the source of these sequences? Why do those particular conditions apply to them? What is it that suggests such an inequality?

Comment: It's a recrational mathematics problem. I'm looking to create a tower of maximal overhang by stacking blocks of variable width one on top of another. The conjecture comes from a belief around what such a maximal stack will look like. Basically, I think we first arrange the blocks in order of decreasing length. At some level we shift the bottom section of blocks then place them on left side of the largest block (block j!). This section acts as a counterbalance for the top-most block. Proving this inequality (as well as a large series of already proven lemmas) would confirm this.

Comment: A full history of related problems is in this paper: https://math.dartmouth.edu/~pw/papers/maxover.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your conjecture fails for $n \ge 7$ (and maybe for some smaller $n$). The following results are from programming your inequality in [Sage](http://www.sagemath.org/) and testing a variety of patterned sequences.

**1.  First family of counterexamples**

Let $S(a,b) = [a, a-1, a-2, ..., 1, b, b-1, b-2,..., 1]$, of length $a+b$, for positive integers $a,b$.

For any $a \ge 2$, there is some $b^* \gt a$ such that for any $b \ge b^*$, $S(a, b)$ is a counterexample. (The quantity $\ \text{LHS}-\text{RHS}\ $ is a decreasing function of $b$, and falls below $0$ at $b=b^*$.)

Such counterexamples include $S(2, b\ge 11), S(3, b\ge 14), S(4, b\ge 16), S(5,b\ge 19)$, and so on. (I haven't determined a formula for $b^*$.)

The smallest counterexample of this form appears to be
$$S(2,11) = [2, 1, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]$$ for which
 $$\text{LHS} = \frac{79582008868974649241}{15735265132809166560} = 5.0575... <  5.0608... = \frac{1185342437701}{234217526928} = \text{RHS}  $$

**2. Second (shorter) family of counterexamples**

Another family of counterexamples is $[2, b, b, b, b, b, 1]$ with $b \ge 5$. The smallest counterexample of this form appears to be 
$[2, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 1]$, for which
 $$\text{LHS} = \frac{3515219}{1225224} = 2.869... <   2.881... = \frac{30446902}{10567557} = \text{RHS}  $$

---

Here's the core of the program (note the indexing adjustments due to Python lists being $0$-based):

```
def lhs(L,j):
    n = len(L)
    tot = (L[0] + L[n-1])/sum(L)
    for i in [j+1..n-2]: tot += L[i]^2 / ( sum(L[0:i+1])*( L[n-1] + sum(L[1:i+1]) ) )
    return (L[n-1] + sum(L[1:j+1]))*tot

def rhs(L,j):
    n = len(L)
    tot = L[n-1]/sum(L)
    for i in [j+1..n-2]: tot += L[i]^2 / ( sum(L[0:i+1])*( L[n-1] + sum(L[0:i+1]) ) )
    return (L[n-1] + sum(L[0:j+1]))*tot 

for b in [3..8]:
    L = [2,b,b,b,b,b,1]; left = lhs(L,1); right = rhs(L,1)
    print b, left.n(), right.n(), (left-right).n()

> 3 1.96695167577521 1.92603768780239 0.0409139879728115
> 4 2.41522132314971 2.40469223123685 0.0105290919128582
> 5 2.86904190580661 2.88116752055371 -0.0121256147470981
> 6 3.32586148147269 3.35536963036963 -0.0295081488969435
> 7 3.78448484495198 3.82769776396051 -0.0432129190085339
> 8 4.24427752155089 4.29855086580553 -0.0542733442546420
```

Comment: I'm getting the same thing. This counterexample takes my paper one step forward and two steps back. Thanks for the step forward though!

Answer (score 0):

Edit: nvm, denominators of the first fraction in the sums are different.

Both sums share:

$(a_n+a_2+\cdots+a_j)\left(\sum_{i=j+1}^{n-1}{\frac{a_i^2}{(a_1+\cdots+a_i)(a_n+a_2+\cdots + a_i)}}+\frac{a_n}{a_1+\cdots+a_n}\right)$

If you subtract that out of the first sum, the following remains:

$(n-j-1)(a_n+a_2+\cdots+a_j)\left(\dfrac{a_1}{a_1+\cdots+a_i}\right)$ (why?)

Likewise for the 2nd sum:

$a_1\left(\sum_{i=j+1}^{n-1}{\frac{a_i^2}{(a_1+\cdots+a_i)(a_n+a_2+\cdots + a_i)}}+\frac{a_n}{a_1+\cdots+a_n}\right)$

remains. (why?)

Comment: You write that both sums share: $$(a_n+a_2+\cdots+a_j)\left(\sum_{i=j+1}^{n-1}{\frac{a_i^2}{(a_1+\cdots+a_i)(a_n+a_2+\cdots + a_i)}}+\frac{a_n}{a_1+\cdots+a_n}\right).$$ I can't see how this is true - the denominator in each sum is slightly different.

Comment: You're right, didn't catch that...does make things more complicated.

Comment: Yep. Wish it were that easy! But thanks for looking at it. I'll keep thinking.